# Expect (fail-at-end)

Tags: google-truth

Can somebody show me a complete minimal example for fail at end behaviour?

[The docs I found](http://google.github.io/truth/comparison) says just:

```
expect.that(actual).isEqualTo(expected); // supplied by @Rule
```

Use case: I would like to have one test, multiple asserts (assertions on the same object, but I would like to see all assert failures, because the test itself is a long-running process).

Answer (score 1):

[`Expect`](http://google.github.io/truth/api/0.33/com/google/common/truth/Expect.html) is intended to be used as a [JUnit `@Rule`](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/rules). You'll see in the source code that the `AssertionError` is thrown after the test finishes, in the [rule's `apply()` method](https://github.com/google/truth/blob/e319cf4/core/src/main/java/com/google/common/truth/Expect.java#L168). Here's a simplified version of what it does:

```
public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
  // this invokes the test, collecting failures in gatherer
  base.evaluate();
  // after the test finishes the failures are collected and thrown
  if (!gatherer.getMessages().isEmpty()) {
    throw new AssertionError(gatherer.toString());
  }
}
```

There's an [example usage of `Expect`](https://github.com/google/truth/blob/e319cf48/core/src/test/java/com/google/common/truth/ExampleTest.java#L73) in the unit tests (which isn't to say it shouldn't be better-documented elsewhere). Essentially, just add a line like:

```
@Rule public final Expect expect = Expect.create();
```

Then use `expect.that(foo)....` to make assertions about `foo` that don't cause the test to fail-fast, instead failing once the test is complete.

Comment: As of 1.0 there's now better documentation on [`Expect`](https://truth.dev/api/1.0/com/google/common/truth/Expect.html).